# CollectionType embedded in another CollectionType : customize entry block form theme

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I try to create a page with a two-level embedded form.

Let's say I have an entity which represents a web page. I consider that I can have blocs on a page so I have a collection of "Block" entities in my "Page" entity. Then I consider that a bloc can contains subblocs (and other attributes obviously) so I have a collection of "SubBlock" entities in my "Block" entity.

When I use the prototypes generated by Symfony, there is no problem. But actually, I want to custom the prototypes attributes. To customize the first level (the blocks collection), I read the documentation (symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype) and everything works great. The name of the overrided block is : **_web_page_blocks_entry_widget**

The real problem is for the second level (a bloc which contains subblocks). I would like to override the twig prototype but I cannot find the good name to use. I tryed a lot of names but nothing work.

Considering my entities :

- WebPage
- WebPageBlock
- WebPageSubBlock

I tried :

- _web_page_blocks_subBlocks_entry_widget
- _web_page_subBlocks_entry_widget
- _web_page_sub_block_subBlocks_entry_widget
- ...

But nothing seems to work. Does anybody know the exact rule to apply in this case to override the default prototype generated block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you got the following fields:

```
// WebPageType
$builder->add('blocks', CollectionType::class);

// BlockType
$builder->add('subBlocks', CollectionType::class);
```

To override `subBlocks` entry theme block you should use:

```
{% block _web_page_blocks_entry_subBlocks_entry_widget %}
```